# Problems with Fragments with logs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can't get a fragments example to run. Here is my code and my log.

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String TAG = "Shakespeare";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v(TAG, "in MainActivity onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(TAG, "in MainActivity onCreate: super.onCreate");
    FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);
    Log.v(TAG, "in MainActivity onCreate FragmentManager");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.v(TAG, "in MainActivity onCreate setContentView");

}
```

Here is my XML file

```
<fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And here are the logs.

onCreateView: id=0x7f050002 fname=com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment existing=null
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 <FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/details"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayo

Comment: That's the actual xml file, it won't render correctly above, but I do have it nested in a linearlayout, and I do have the version and encoding header.

Answer (score 0):

This class of the fragment specified in your layout file must exist in your Java code:

com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment

so you'll have to create this class, with the correct package name too.